# Определить, входит ли символ в TextView внутри if

Tags: java, android, строки, textview, android-textview

Вопрос можно разделить на два пункта:

1. Существует ли метод, который возвращает `true`, если символ встречается в строке/TextView и соответственно `false` в обратном случае?
2. Если нет, как можно проверить это условие в if не создавая отдельного метода, так как имхо создавать метод, который будет вызван один раз не очень эстетично.

Comment: myTextView.getText().toString.contains(something)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, в классе `String` существует такой метод:

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
```

где `s` – объект класса, реализующего интерфейс `CharSequence`.

**UPD**:

Проверить наличие символа `char c` в строке `String str` можно таким образом:

```
boolean contains = str.contains(String.valueOf(c));
```

или таким:

```
boolean contains = str.indexOf(c) != -1 ? true : false;
```

В первом случае `char c` преобразуется к типу `String` и вызывается метод `String.contains(...)`, во втором – с помощью метода `String.indexOf(...)` производится поиск позиции символа `char c` в строке `str`, если заданного символа в строке нет, то метод возвращает `-1`, если есть – его позицию в строке.

Comment: Можно поконкретней, например если нужно проверить наличие `char c` в строке `String str`, как будет выглядеть вызов метода?

Comment: @Evgeniy, Обновил ответ.